# Threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I am working on a personal project and I have the following problem and I know I have to used threads to do this but any help would be appreciated

I want to build a thread that sleeps for 2 seconds or 2000ms and then runs a methods after the 2 seconds, how can I do this I know how to make the thread that sleeps for 2sec but not how I can make a method/function run after the 2 secs

Comment: I tried making a thread and then executing the method right after I start the thread which I know is wrong but I dont have any better ideas

Comment: Have you read any materials on threading with Java? Have you googled any pages?

Comment: So you want to sleep and then call a custom function? Why don't you just do that?

Answer (score 2):

IF you call sleep(2000) in the main thread, your whole application will be blocked :)

The trick is not to call it in your main thread. There is something in Java that is the  `ScheduledExecutorService`, that will do perfectly for you. Check out here for examples: [**link**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html)

Using it will allow you to "dispatch" actions of your choice off the main thread, thus creating more side threads, and schedule them to execute with certain time offset of your choice.

You just need to create a class that implements `Runnable` and in the implementation of the `run` method do whatever you need to do. The only other step is to submit instances of those (or maybe other classes, if you need different "jobs" to be submitted) to the `ScheduledExecutorService` instance you've created.

Answer (score 0):

Have the thread sleep (for the desired period) in a loop you insert in the `run` method. Then, Invoke the method/function in the loop body. I would recommend you read up on a thread life cycle.